# Can't seem to override erroneous .ebextensions config AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch

I am deploying zip files from my CI server to an Elastic Beanstalk instance using EB CLI. This has been working fine up until now using both manual and automated deployments.

Yesterday I started playing about with CloudWatch logging, and tried out a [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/) to kick things off. In terms of deployment, things were still working fine. I then added in an intentional mistake to test what would happen if the deployment failed:

```
  ######################################################
 ## Alarms

 AWSEBCWLHttp5xxCountAlarm :
   nonsensechangeheree
   Type : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
   DependsOn : AWSEBCWLHttpNon5xxMetricFilter
   Properties :
     AlarmDescription: "Application is returning too many 5xx responses (count too high)."
     MetricName: CWLHttp5xx
     Namespace: {"Fn::Join":["/", ["ElasticBeanstalk", {"Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName"}]]}
     Statistic: Sum
     Period: 60
     EvaluationPeriods: 1
     Threshold: 10
     ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
     AlarmActions:
       - "Fn::If":
           - SNSTopicExists
           - "Fn::FindInMap":
               - AWSEBOptions
               - options
               - EBSNSTopicArn
           - { "Ref" : "AWS::NoValue" }
```

When I then removed the mistake, I was still getting an error message when running `eb deploy`:

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - The configuration file .ebextensions/cwl-webrequest-metrics.config in application version talisker-0.0.26 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: while scanning a simple key
 in "<reader>", line 125, column 3:
  nonsensechangeheree
  ^
could not found expected ':'
 in "<reader>", line 126, column 10:
        Type : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
         ^
, JSON exception: Unexpected character (#) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

No matter what I do to pass in the correct config, this error still shows! I have checked the ZIP file I am uploading and I get the error whether I include `.ebextensions` or not. I have tried deleting and re-uploading the ZIP to S3. I have tried rebooting the server. I have tried manually uploading an entirely new version.

Is there somewhere this config persists where I can overwrite it? I have also tried deleting the offending alarm in the console.

I'm sure there is something simple I have overlooked, so any suggestions (obvious or otherwise) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: I couldn't find the root cause of the issue. I think I ended up solving it by either terminating and restarting the instance, or cloning it and rebuilding it that way.